# Remote System Monitor for Ubuntu and Android

Tags: android, monitor, system, remote

I'm looking for a software for Ubuntu that is similar to [Remote System Monitor](https://www.trigonesoft.com/)

I would like to access to my data and see them from my Android phone.

Could you suggest any software like that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can use it as

1.TeamViewer for Android

2. VNC Viewer for Android
3. KDE Connect
4. DroidMote Client
5. Remote Mouse

6.Termux.... then you have to use  ssh

7.it's a bit complicate but you can use server to  check your data in your laptop but it won't gives you advantage for fire any commands ...

Comment: Thanks but it is not to control the server from the mobile, I want only the temperature information, GPU, CPU. There is a program called Remote System monitor but it is only for Windows.

Comment: ohhh sorry I thought you were talking about view pics and video read docs etc....ok now let's try other options ..like Termux if you get ssh access then you can fire command and check it what you want